# using # to get the length of an array does not work

Tags: lua

```
> t = {"a", "b", "c"}
> #t
stdin:1: unexpected symbol near '#'
>
```

Using the "#" sign can get the length of an array, right? So, why is the above code not working? Thanks.

Comment: Which Lua version are you using (`lua -v` in shell or `print(_VERSION)` in Lua)?

Comment: The lua I'm using, is Lua 5.2.4

Comment: Seemless printing in interactive mode was added in 5.3. Try `=#t` or `print(#t)` instead.